# Synchronizing external USB HDD with internal HDD

Tags: sync, external-hard-drive

I want to automatically synchronize some specific folders on an external USB HDD and an internal HDD whenever I connect the external drive to my PC.

How can I do this? Are there any free solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows then [SyncToy from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15155) is freely available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't automatic, but I'll post here because it is a great solution and might be helpful for others who come to this post.

I put [Toucan Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan) on the external drive. 
Set up the sync or backup exactly the way I want it. 
Then run it whenever necessary when the drive is attached.